# Why use the GetModuleHandleA function to get a handle to the executable?

Tags: winapi, assembly

As I am learning reverse engineering, I'm doing Lena's tutorials on the matter. On the third exercice, I don't understand why the **GetModuleHandleA** function is called to get a handle of the current file. Just after that, the program checks if it failed and show the *bad boy*. (Pop-up we want to remove.)

Because ASM code worth a thounsand words, here's more details:

```
    PUSH  0 // Entry point!
    CALL  <JMP.&KERNEL32.GetModuleHandleA>   // Returns 00400000 (RegisterMe.<STRUCT IMAGE_DOS_HEADER>)
    MOV   DWORD PTR DS:[40311C], EAX
    CMP   EAX,0
,-  JE    SHORT RegisterMe.00401024
|   [...] // Annoying pop-up
`-> [...] // Rest of the program
```

According to the MSDN page for [GetModuleHandleA,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) :

> If this parameter is NULL, **GetModuleHandle** returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file).

I have two questions:

1. Why does the **GetModuleHandleA** returns a pointer to `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`? I expected it to return a handle to a *file*.
2. In which cicumstances would the jump have been taken? (In other words, how could the **GetModuleHandleA** fail?)
   To me, the only scenario that can skip the annoying pop-up is if the function fails. Am I wrong or is this not realistic?

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` and must return pointer to `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`.

Comment: Documentation is sloppy. It returns a module handle, `HMODULE`. That's not a file handle. It's actually the base address of the loaded module.

Comment: Read that documentation as "returns a handle to **the module created from** the file used to create the calling process (.exe file)."

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to bypass some copy protection code, and the code has some defences against that.  (For example self-modifying code, or patching the indirect to `GetModuleHandleA` to jump somewhere more interesting.)

Comment: GetModuleHandle() goes back to ancient 16-bit Windows versions, back when a module was actually represented by a handle.  No longer necessary, the flat memory space of a 32-bit or 64-bit process makes the load address of the module now serve as a reliable identifier.  Lots of reasons to use it, retrieving embedded resources and discovering the install directory for example, the kind of things that are interesting to a popup.  It won't fail, but always testing winapi return codes is entirely standard.

Comment: We don't know, which parameter you are passing. The call can fail, if the parameter you are passing does not name a module loaded into the process.

Comment: @IInspectable - from code visible that `GetModuleHandleA(0)` called

Comment: True. That call can't fail, unless it is hooked, one way or another.